# Find one to be doing/ doing

Tags: meaning

Are all correct? Any difference in meaning?

> 1 I found him to be sitting by the fire.
>
> 2 I found him sitting by the fire.
>
> 3 I found him to be a swindler.
>
> 4 I found him being a swindler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(2) is more natural than (1), because we usually use *found him to be* in relation to a personal quality (as in (3)) rather than a temporary situation.

(4) is unidiomatic. (It implies *I found him in the act of swindling someone*, but it's not a natural way to say that.)

Comment: Could you elaborate whether 1 is wrong or what?

Comment: As I said, it's much less natural than (2) for the reason I gave, but I suppose it isn't definitively 'wrong'.